# Can't close Form in Powershell when using fuction

Tags: forms, winforms, powershell, showdialog

I'm trying to throw up a control-less window in Powershell that hovers on top while the script is still executing.  Once the remaining is code is finished, I want to remove the control-less window.

I've got everything down except how to remove the window itself.  $Form.close() doesn't work, and if I had to guess it's because it can't access $Form in the function.

So I'm at a loss.  How do I remove the window?

```
function goForm
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Label.Text = "This form is very simple.  
In some cases, it will be larger.

And have spaces.

Like this."
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Progress"
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Form.AutoSize = $True
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.Controlbox = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12,   [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" 
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
}

start-job $function:goForm

Start-Sleep -m 5000

$Form.Close()

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$oReturn=[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("The other window should be gone." , "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Start-Job, the form is created in another PowerShell process so you can't access the form by variable in the original PowerShell process.  However, you don't need to show this modal and hence you don't need to use `Start-Job`.  Just use `.Show()` instead e.g.:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Label.Text = @"
This form is very simple.
In some cases, it will be larger.

And have spaces.

Like this.
"@
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Progress"
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Form.AutoSize = $True
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.Controlbox = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12,   [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})

$Form.Show()
$Form.Close()
```

Comment: I started with .Show before using .ShowDialog.  It works fine in the PowerShell ISE, but when run externally, the dialog box doesn't show the label or text.  So the box comes up for the 5 seconds (missing from your post) but it's translucent-like.  No text is visible.

Comment: Admittedly I only tried this on PowerShell v5 but on v5 it works from the console.  Which version of PowerShell are you using?  There was a version where the console ran MTA and that might be causing problems.

Comment: 2.0.  I updated to 3, and it worked fine.  My need assumes the lowest common version of PS for Windows 7.  Is there a way to internally switch the script to run as STA?

Comment: Anyone know how to switch to STA internally?

Comment: That sounds about right.  IIRC they switched to STA by V3.  For v2 and higher you can invoke PowerShell.exe with the `-STA` parameter.